# Не загружаются файлы на сайты ни в одном браузере в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, google-chrome

Chrome крашится с страницей "Опаньки", Firefox выдает ошибку в консоль. Причем Thunderbird и клиент Dropbox могут выгружать файлы. Так же в Firefox на сайт Dropbox можно загрузить файлы и картинки в twitter через буфер обмена.
Лог консоли Firefox, при загрузке файла на vk.com:

```
NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST:  upload.js:691:0
POST 
XHR 
http://q85.queuev4.vk.com/im026 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 25074мс]
NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST:  upload.js:691:0
[57.413]  drop key 3iMVxK2IhfPs_lQA3AVQeBYUvEMH2FPtHdxgJ56Gc0sUS8YvqhG676QmiuQovfzl 50597
```

Comment: А если создать нового пользователя и попробовать под ним?

Comment: Ничего не изменится, пробовал.

Comment: Не изменится потому что ты так думаешь или потому что ты уже пробовал?

Comment: Ну, расскажите, что до этого делали (обновляли/удаляли/изменяли)? пробовали ли уже переустановку chrome/firefox? разные ли пути пробовали указывать браузеру при загрузке файлов? Например, такая ошибка может быть, если подсовывать в путь к файлу что-то, чего не существует.

Comment: был установлен пакет libc6 для пакета ruby, после которого удалились пакеты locales, все языковые пакеты(language-pack) и ubuntu-minimal. Далее были обновлены все пакеты и установлена opera, в которой тоже ничего не загружается на сайты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема найдена. Дело в том, что когда удалились locales, поменялся язык системы и сменились названия папок. Где-то остались старые ссылки и теперь браузеры не могут найти файлы. Можно сменить названия папок или создать ссылки на них с старым названием.

Comment: я был почти близок, обновляйтесь осторожней. Разберитесь с локалью, подменять имена директорий - костыль.

Comment: ок, спасибо за советы, вывели на мысль.